# Google Analytics content experiment test effect of bypassing stage in checkout process

Tags: php, google-analytics, ab-testing

Struggling to find any clear instructions / examples on this, and any suggestions would be appreciated...

I have an `e-commerce` website which includes multiple steps eg

1) select product

2) select upgrade option

3) checkout, and wish to test the effect on conversions when removing step 2 (upgrade option).

Having trawled through documentation, I think it will require the `server-side` implementation `route`, but haven't yet found a clear example I can understand best route to implementation.

Any suggestions / links would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/experiments-server-side) is about as good as it gets in the way of documentation. If you think it’s basically unworkable, I’d have to agree.